# How to test abstract contracts using truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, test

Is it possible to test abstract contract using truffle? If yes, how I can to do it?

Comment: Yes, inherit the contract, implement the missing functions (to do whatever), and test those that weren't missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to test them since you can't deploy abstract contracts.

Therefore, you need to write a contract that inherits it, using the keyword "is" and implements all abstract methods. Then, you can use this contract to do actual testing.